# A quick subject/object question

Tags: questions, subjects

Here is the sentence:

> Han wants to become a worker.

I would like to ask about his job intentions. Which one would be the correct version to do that:

1) Who does Han want to become?
2) Who Han wants to become?

I assume 1) is correct, since A WORKER would be an object and not a subject. Am I right?

Comment: Unless Han is undergoing a "transfiguration" spell such as in  Harry Potter...I suggest you use _what_.

Comment: Why is your question quick? Are you urging people to give you a quick answer? Your question is either good or bad, and I suggest it is bad, in which case it will not be “quick”, but “dead”. (Look it up.)

Comment: Cascabel, thank you for a reply. Could you please write the correct version? Is it: WHAT does Hant want to become?

David, my question was intended to be quick, because (I thought) it was based on a trivial grammar, which says: when formulating the "Who" questions, we do not use inversion and an axuliarly word, unless we are asking about the object not the subject. For example: Who wants to become a worker - Han does. Han is a subject. But: Who does Han want to become - Han wants to become a worker. Here a worker is an object. There are no bad questions, every question is a call for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Han wants to become a worker you need to know what type of work he wants to do, so, if you are the hiring Manager and have been asked if you have any jobs Han could do:

"What [*type of work*] does Han want to do?" is the correct question.

"Who does Han want to become?" asks a different question, that is, 'what' or 'which' *different* human being [who] does Han want to change into?

Does Han want to become the Queen of England?  Does HE wish to become a woman?  Neither are really appropriate or achievable, if his aim is to obtain a job.

The second version: "Who Han wants to become[?]"  is not really a question.  It is properly a statement of Han's intent, in response to the question: "Who do you want to become?"  In this case the correct answer might be: "A better person."

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation.
Maybe I am misunderstood:
(I will swap the vague worker for a concrete word: the teacher). So, Han is 10. He is a student/a pupil. He studies. (when he grows up) Han wants to become a teacher. Rearange the structure, so the sentence becomes a question. 1) Who does Han want to become? (He wants to become a teacher)
2) Who Han wants to become? (He wants to become a teacher)
or 3) What does Han want to become? (He wants to become a teacher)
or even 4) What Han wants to become? (He wants to become a teacher) ?

Comment: If I were the teacher asking Han's parents about Han's future employment choices, I would ask: What does Han want to do for a career? or "What does Han want to do for a job?"  'To do' in the sense of 'doing work' (Physics, Force x distance= Newton metres), expend energy, make something...   "Who does Han want to become?" seems to me to be asking something more personal, more about the type of person or personality Han may want to become, "A thoughtful person". / "An extrovert" / "successful", rather than the thing he wants to do to earn money [the job].

Comment: thank you, NeilB!